# Adding XML record into existing XML file using XML::Twig

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I was trying to add a block of content under some xpath in the existing XML file. I was new to this XML parsing using Perl. But I was supposed to do using this [XML::Twig](https://www.metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig).

Input :

```
  <model name="MDL_#USER#" oid="#LOOP#">
<appli name="ERETAIL" oid="2">
    <schema desc="Parameters schema" enab="YES" name="Parameters" oid="1" prio="1">
        <bean enab="YES" labl="Parameters" name="ERETAILPARA" oid="3" vers="1.0" xpos="0" ypos="0">
            <para>
                <root>
                    <row desc="password encryption mode" name="OISENCRYPT" value="BASE64"/>
                </root>
            </para>         
        </bean>
    </schema>
</appli>
```

Output:

```
   <model name="MDL_#USER#" oid="#LOOP#">
<appli name="ERETAIL" oid="2">
    <schema desc="Parameters schema" enab="YES" name="Parameters" oid="1" prio="1">
        <bean enab="YES" labl="Parameters" name="ERETAILPARA" oid="3" vers="1.0" xpos="0" ypos="0">
            <para>
                <root>
                    <row desc="password encryption mode" name="OISENCRYPT" value="BASE64"/>
                    <row name="INTERNAL" desc="" value="">
                        <row name="PATH" desc="Path" value="#PATH#" />
                        <row name="EXT" desc="Adresse" value="#GAIAIP#" />
                    </row>  
                </root>
            </para>         
        </bean>
    </schema>
</appli>
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your below input 
but If i tried to give path like as below my 
$twig = XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { '/model/appli[@name="ERETAIL"]/schema[@name="Parameters"]/bean[@labl="Parameters‌​"]/para/root/' => \&add_rows, }, pretty_print => 'indented', ); 
i was getting an error like below 
unrecognized expression in handler: '/model/appli[@name="ERETAIL"]/schema[@name= "Parameters"]/bean[@labl="Parameters"]/para/root/' 
 Can you please help me

Comment: remove the last / in the path

Answer (score 2):

For [XML::Twig](http://www.metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig), create a handler to modify the element you want to change. In that handler, create the new elements that you want then paste them into the element as children:

```
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = <<'HERE';
<model name="MDL_#USER#" oid="#LOOP#">
<appli name="ERETAIL" oid="2">
    <schema desc="Parameters schema" enab="YES" name="Parameters" oid="1" prio="1">
        <bean enab="YES" labl="Parameters" name="ERETAILPARA" oid="3" vers="1.0" xpos="0" ypos="0">
            <para>
                <root>
                    <row desc="password encryption mode" name="OISENCRYPT" value="BASE64"/>
                </root>
            </para>         
        </bean>
    </schema>
</appli>
</model>
HERE

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'bean/para/root' => \&add_rows,
        },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    );
$twig->parse( $xml );
$twig->print;
```

Remember that in the handler, you get the current element as `$_`:

```
sub add_rows {
    XML::Twig::Elt->new( row => {
        name  => 'PATH',
        desc  => 'Path',
        value => '#PATH#'
        } )->paste( last_child => $_ );

    XML::Twig::Elt->new( row => {
        name  => 'EXT',
        desc  => 'Adresse',
        value => '#GAIAIP#'
        } )->paste( last_child => $_ );
    }
```

Comment: Hello Brian,
Thanks for your input but If i tried to give path like as below
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        '/model/appli[@name="ERETAIL"]/schema[@name="Parameters"]/bean[@labl="Parameters"]/para/root/' => \&add_rows,
        },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    );
i was getting an error like below unrecognized expression in handler: '/model/appli[@name="ERETAIL"]/schema[@name=
"Parameters"]/bean[@labl="Parameters"]/para/root/' at sample2.pl line 60 Can you please help me

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Maybe someone can help you.